# Evaluating properties inside Spring Expression Lang (SpEL)

Tags: java, spring, properties, expression, spring-el

Our service has a process that is scheduled according to a properties file, reading the property **refreshIntervalMillis**. Its value is injected directly in a Quartz trigger with this configuration:

```
<bean name="trigger"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean "
    p:repeatInterval="${refreshIntervalMillis}"> 
...
</bean>
```

However, the admins that install this service think in terms of hours/days, so in order to make thing easier for them, we changed this to:

1. Renamed **refreshIntervalMillis** to **refreshIntervalMinutes**
2. Changed to code above to the following:

```
p:repeatInterval="#{ 1000 * 60 * T(java.lang.Integer).valueOf(@configurationProperties['garbageLevelWatcher.refreshIntervalMinutes'])}"
```

Note: the properties object is exposed as a bean named "configurationProperties"

Is there a simpler syntax to accomplish the same?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`"#{T(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit).MINUTES.toMillis( @configurationProperties['garbageLevelWatcher.refreshIntervalMinutes'])}"`

EDIT:

Or...

```
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="configurationProperties"
<util:constant id = "MINUTES" static-field="java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES" />
```

and

```
"#{@MINUTES.toMillis(${garbageLevelWatcher.refreshIntervalMinutes})}"
```

Comment: Why java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit? the spring applicationContext loading is done once and in one thread

Comment: Just that it has convenient conversion methods - no need for "1000 * 60" - the OP asked for simpler syntax. TimeUnit is an enum with a whole bunch of conversion methods. When the expression is evaluated is completely irrelevant to this discussion.

Comment: Gary, nice tip, I've forgot about TimeUnit methods. I've upvoted your answer. I'll keep the question open for a few days waiting for more ideas to make even it more simpler, ie. can we put MINUTES and the properties in the context, so that we can just write "#{MINUTES.toMillis(${garbageLevelWatcher.refreshIntervalMinutes})}" (ideally...)

Comment: I edited my answer with an alternative; if you have a common <import/> file you could put the constant in that.

Comment: Just a note that `@MINUTES` can be written as just `MINUTES`, at least it worked for me in XML config.

Answer (score 1):

If the properties are looked up by a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, @PropertySource or  <context:property-placeholder /> and the context is aware of it

You can write it like this:

```
p:repeatInterval="#{ 1000 * 60 * T(java.lang.Integer).valueOf('${garbageLevelWatcher.refreshIntervalMinutes}') }"
```

Comment: Yes, the properties are also looked up by context:property-placeholder. How can we make the SpEL context aware of them?

Comment: As i know it's automatically aware of it

Comment: the context-property-placeholder just needs to be defined in the application-context.xml, as opposed to the webmvc-context.xml which sets up the web context-