# How to get SpEL to add two numbers

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I want to compute my port number inside application.properties like this:

```
server.port=#{ 1 + ${myapp.web.server.port.ssl} }
myapp.web.server.port.ssl=8300
```

But when I start my Spring Boot app all I get is an execption.

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type java.lang.String to type java.lang.Integer]
```

The Mathematical Operators section of the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) suggests that it should work, but it doesn't.

Inside Spring it gets as far as calling:

```
GenericConversionService.convert("#{ 1 + 8300 }", java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer)
```

But there is no logic in there for recognising it's SpEL.   It's like it's not recognising it's SpEL at all.  However if I change the expression to `#{ n1 + ${myapp.web.server.port.ssl} }` then I get the following exception, showing that it is being evaluated as SpEL:

```
SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'n1' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
```

How can I make SpEL add one to the value of another property?

**Update:**

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510563/evaluating-properties-inside-spring-expression-lang-spel) so I tried a similar approach:

server.port=#{T(java.lang.Integer).parseInt('${fire.web.server.port.ssl}') + 1}

But that still doesn't work.  For some reason it's not treating it as an SpEL expression.  But is does treat it as a SpEL expression if there is a syntax error!

Comment: did it ever work?

Comment: oh wow, I don't remember, this was 5 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that only from config, but not from properties:

```
<bean class="...">
   <property name="port" value="#{1 + ${myapp.web.server.port.ssl}}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I think you might be right. But it doesn't make complete sense, as if I put `#{ n1 + ${myapp.web.server.port.ssl} }` then I get SpEL exception.  So as some point it is treating it as a SpEL expression!

Comment: That's true, because SpEL doesn't know what is `n1`. If it is a property from file you should use it like `${n1}` too. It will work, if you have a bean with `n1` name. Otherwise yes: it does not make sence even for me.

Comment: But if I change n1 to 1, then I get a non-SpEL exception saying that it can't convert a string to an interger, and there is no mention of SpEL in the stacktrace.  So it's as if it's not being treated as an SpEL expression.

Comment: How about this `#{1 + Integer.parseInt(${myapp.web.server.port.ssl})}`?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that `${myapp.web.server.port.ssl}` is evaluated as `String`, try something like this

```
#{1 + new Integer(props['myapp.web.server.port.ssl'])}
```

where `props` is the bean holding your properties.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work because I don't have `props` as an object.  Updating question.

Comment: Can you try this `#{1 + new Integer(myapp.web.server.port.ssl)}`?